# How can I print a message say 'NO SLOTS' if there are no items in the array of that particular date in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a project in which i am displaying time slots(of next 7 days) of a doctor and i recieve an array which consists of objects of scheduleTime type.

```
export class ScheduleTime{
    date: string;
    hours: number;
    minutes: number;
}
```

now i am displaying these slots to the patient.

my html code for displaying the slots is :

```
    <div *ngFor="let todayDate of dates; let z = index" class="dateBox">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">{{fullDate[z] | date: 'fullDate'}}</div>
            <div *ngFor="let time of ScheduleTime; let i = index">
                <div *ngIf="time.date != todayDate">No available Slots</div>
                     <div *ngIf="todayDate == time.date">
                         <div class="timeSlots" [style.background-color]="startSelect>0 && endSelect>0 && i>startSelect && i<endSelect?'rgb(207, 200, 238)':null" [ngClass]="{'startClass': time.hours == st.sh && time.minutes == st.sm && startDate == time.date, 'endClass': time.hours == et.eh && time.minutes == et.em && startDate == time.date}"
                         (click)='timeSelector(time,i,todayDate)'>
                         {{time.hours}}:{{time.minutes | zero}}
                             </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
             <br>
         <hr class="timeBoxHr">
    </div>
```

now the problem is : if there is no time slot for that particular date then it should display the text no time slots

What I have done till now is

If todayDate and the date in the array do not match then print the message "No available slots", else print the slots.

[CHECK THIS IMAGE: In this image, I have 5 elements in the array and corresponding time slots are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrnQc.png)

Comment: What are the values of `ScheduleTime` and `dates`?

Comment: @Kenny ScheduleTime is the name of an array having 3 fields: minutes, hours and date. And dates is an array which contains date of 7 further days.

Comment: Add a sample data of them in your question, so that we can figure out exact problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use property binding to add message .
eg in your html code write like this
{{message}}
and in your typescript code
you can assign value to it by
this.message="Sorry! No slots available"

Comment: Tell me something I don't know. ;)